# While parsing an HTML response getting rid of CDATA

Tags: html, xml, scala

On hitting an API , I am getting a text/html response. I am trying to parse the response in Scala using

```
 xmlObj = XML.loadString(response)
```

However as certain sections are not enclosed in the ![CDATA tag the parser is giving :
    SAX Parser exception as it is not able to parse characters like &#0 .

Can someone tell me how to go about it as all I want to do is extract the content enclosed with the "body" tag.

Right now I am trying something like this:

```
xmlResult = (xmlObj // "body").text
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You will hit more problems trying to read HTML as well-formed XML (unclosed tags). You might try java [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for reading HTML.

Comment: is there a scala equivalent for jsoup?

Comment: I found some results for "Scala JSoup." As I did not use Scala+JSoup, I leave the picking for you.